# Python converting date/time string with a timezone offset

Tags: python

I have something like `Fri Aug 03 15:16:37 +0000 2012` and I want to convert it to `03-08-2012`.

I also have some dates as Unix timestamp like `1344006622`, and here I am simply do:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1344006622).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

But this works only for the Unix timestamp. How can I convert the first one?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Python 2 with `dateutil`

As far as I know, Python 2 only provides a `%Z` (capital Z) for timezone *names*,  but you have an *offset* (`+0000`), but there is a library called [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that can help you:

```
>>> import dateutil
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('Fri Aug 03 15:16:37 +0000 2012')
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 3, 15, 16, 37, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

In the above example I used Python 2.7.9 with dateutil 2.4.2
You can check your version with

```
>>> dateutil.__version__
'2.4.2'
```

You can install it with `pip install python-dateutil` or if you want to specify a version `pip install python-dateutil==2.4.2`

### Python 3

Since Python 3.2 there is a `%z` that parses the `+0000` timezone info:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('Fri Aug 03 15:16:37 +0000 2012', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 3, 15, 16, 37, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

For an explanation of the parameters used please refer to [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Comment: Thanks. Since I am using Python 2.7, do you have any further idea?

Comment: This did the job for me. Thank you very much ;)